# Domain gets internal server error but ip works

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, gunicorn

Yesterday I hosted a website on aws ubuntu and created a hosted zone, then added the name servers to my domain name and 30 min later everything worked fine. I could go to the domain name and it would work. However later that night the wsgi crashed and I had to reconnect (ssh) to it and when I started it again, going to the Domain would get an internal server error but going to the ip address would give me the website.

I checked and I entered all the name servers correctly and the ip address was entered correctly. I let the server run over night and I still get an internal server error when I go to the domain name.

Edit: Now I get redirected to the website that I purchased the domain from

I have looked around and it seems no one else has had this problem so I really don't know where to start trying to fix it.

Comment: If you've run DIG and the nameservers point to route 53, with the correct record pointing to your domain then your application server would be doing the redirect.

Comment: I ran DIG and it shows that my domain is connected to my servers IP address

Comment: Is there anyway to view the access logs to at least validate it hits your server?

Comment: It doesn't even hit my server